# How to add a pause/play function to a running setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to create a pomodoro timer. The website currently looks and functions like this: [POMODOROone](http://developertenzin.github.io/pomodoro)

My timer is counting down correctly so far. However, when I try to add a pause and resume functionality, it breaks. I have tried multiple ways but I haven't had much success. So I removed all my attempts and I have the code for what is working so far. 
So, my question is how would I add a pause/resume functionality to my timer? Also, how would I make my timer stop when I click on any of the positive and negative spans or the inputs?

Here is the Javascript:

```
//decreases break time by 5 mins
function decreaseBreak() {
    var time = document.getElementById("breakInput").value;
    time = parseInt(time, 10);
    var new_time = time - 5;
    if (time == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("breakInput").value = new_time;
    document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = new_time+":00";
}
//increases break time by 5 mins
function increaseBreak() {
    var time = document.getElementById("breakInput").value;
    time = parseInt(time, 10);
    var new_time = time + 5;
    document.getElementById("breakInput").value = new_time;
    document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = new_time+":00";
}
//decreases session time by 5 mins
function decreaseSession() {
    var time = document.getElementById("sessionInput").value;
    time = parseInt(time, 10);
    var new_time = time - 5;
    if (time == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("sessionInput").value = new_time;
    document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = new_time+":00";
}
//increases session time by 5 mins
function increaseSession() {
    var time = document.getElementById("sessionInput").value;
    time = parseInt(time, 10);
    var new_time = time + 5;
    document.getElementById("sessionInput").value = new_time;
    document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = new_time+":00";
}

//countdown timer 


function start() {
    var sec = 60;
    var timerParagraph = document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML;
    var min = timerParagraph.substring(0, timerParagraph.indexOf(":"));
    var time = min * 60;
    min = parseInt(min,10)-1;
    setInterval(function() {
        sec = sec - 1;

        if (sec < 0) {
            min -= 1;
            sec = 59;
        }

        if (min < 0 && sec < 0) {
            clearInterval(start());
        }
        var temp;

        if (min.toString().length == 1 && sec.toString().length == 2) {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = "0" + min + ":" + sec;
        } else if (sec.toString().length == 1 && min.toString().length == 2) {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = min + ":" + "0" + sec;
        } else if (min.toString().length == 1 && sec.toString().length ==1) {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = "0" + min + ":" + "0" + sec;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
        }

    },1000);

}
```

New Updated Code:

```
//decreases break time by 5 mins
function decreaseBreak() {
    var time = document.getElementById("breakInput").value;
    time = parseInt(time, 10);
    var new_time = time - 5;
    if (time == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("breakInput").value = new_time;
    clearInterval(timer); 
    document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = new_time+":00";

}
//increases break time by 5 mins
function increaseBreak() {
    var time = document.getElementById("breakInput").value;
    time = parseInt(time, 10);
    var new_time = time + 5;
    document.getElementById("breakInput").value = new_time;
    document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = new_time+":00";
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
}
//decreases session time by 5 mins
function decreaseSession() {
    var time = document.getElementById("sessionInput").value;
    time = parseInt(time, 10);
    var new_time = time - 5;
    if (time == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("sessionInput").value = new_time;
    document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = new_time+":00";
    clearInterval(timer);
}
//increases session time by 5 mins
function increaseSession() {
    var time = document.getElementById("sessionInput").value;
    time = parseInt(time, 10);
    var new_time = time + 5;
    document.getElementById("sessionInput").value = new_time;
    document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = new_time+":00";
    clearInterval(timer);
}

//countdown timer 

var timer = null;
var sec = 60;


function start() {
    var timerParagraph = document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML;
    var min = timerParagraph.substring(0, timerParagraph.indexOf(":"));
    min = parseInt(min,10)-1;

    function onTimer() {
        sec = sec - 1;

        if (sec < 0) {
            min -= 1;
            if (min == 0 && sec == 0) {
                // When min and second equals zero, timer stops
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            sec = 59;
        }


        if (min.toString().length == 1 && sec.toString().length == 2) {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = "0" + min + ":" + sec;
        } else if (sec.toString().length == 1 && min.toString().length == 2) {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = min + ":" + "0" + sec;
        } else if (min.toString().length == 1 && sec.toString().length ==1) {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = "0" + min + ":" + "0" + sec;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
        }
    }

    timer = setInterval(onTimer,1000);
    console.log("Start timer");

    // when the div is clicked, the timer starts and stops.
    document.getElementById("timerDiv").onclick = function() {
        if (timer) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null; 
        } else {
            timer = setInterval(onTimer,1000);
            console.log("Resume timer");
        }
    }

}
```

This updated code works for the following new actions: 
1. When the timer starts playing, and if the timerDiv is clicked, it will pause. 
2. And when clicked again, it will resume.

Now, when I click on the positive and negative signs and change the time, it changes the time like it should and clears the interval like it is called. However, when I click on the timerDiv again, instead of playing from the start, it resumes playing the time from where it left off. How would I make it so that when I click on the timerDiv again, it counts down from the new time instead of resuming previous time.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval_clearinterval

The way you set your interval and clear it inside of the start() function doesn't make much sense and is probably the cause of your troubles.
The function called every second should be stored with a function name.

```
/*
A wrapper variable is used to keep variables in scope so clearinterval can be used and variables don't interact outside of 'T'.
*/
var T = {
    sec: null,
    timerParagraph: null,
    min: null,
    time: null,
    interval: null,
    //countdown timer 
    start: function(){
        T.interval = setInterval(T.tickClock,1000); 
    },
    pause: function(){
        clearInterval(T.interval);
    },
    reset: function(){
        T.sec = 60;
        T.timerParagraph = document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML;
        T.min = T.timerParagraph.substring(0, T.timerParagraph.indexOf(":"));
        T.time = T.min * 60;
        T.min = parseInt(T.min,10)-1;
    },
    tickClock: function(){
        T.sec = T.sec - 1;

        if (T.sec < 0) {
            T.min -= 1;
            T.sec = 59;
        }

        if (T.min < 0 && T.sec < 0) {
            clearInterval(T.interval);
        }
        if (T.min.toString().length == 1 && T.sec.toString().length == 2) {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = "0" + T.min + ":" + T.sec;
        } else if (T.sec.toString().length == 1 && T.min.toString().length == 2) {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = T.min + ":" + "0" + T.sec;
        } else if (T.min.toString().length == 1 && T.sec.toString().length ==1) {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = "0" + T.min + ":" + "0" + T.sec;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("timerParagraph").innerHTML = T.min + ":" + T.sec;
        }
    }
    /*
    Use T.reset() to set the clock back to the beginning. Use T.start to begin the interval and T.pause to stop the interval.
    You may need to record how far within a second the pause is used so you can offset the second when you start again.
    This would mean having a settimeout which counts in milliseconds or something.
    */
}
```

I haven't tested this code so beware of potential typos, although I did double check for those.

To make the timer pause use onclick="T.pause()" within the elements you want to have that functionality.
Or within javascript using

```
element.onclick = function(){
    T.pause();
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: I tried your code, and it didn't work. Even the start function didn't run. I tried putting an inline code as well as through javascript. No luck :(

Comment: Can you show me the code you used? maybe you could debug with console.log and other tools such as google chrome dev tools.
Only allow T.start() to be called after the onload event has fired.

Comment: Hey George, thanks for your help. I couldn't really make your code work but it gave me some ideas, and I have made the pause and resume functionality work. However, now when I click on the "add" and "minus" signs, it changes the div tag's content to the input like it should but when I click on the timerDiv again, instead of playing the timer from the start, it resumes from where it left off. How would I fix this issue?

Comment: I found a typo in my original code, timeParagraph in the declaration should be timerParagraph. If you fix that then it should work. Open the console to look for other potential typos or issues and I suggest you try that code style.
The setInterval will just call the function to change the time, it won't reset the sec to 60. So when you next call setInterval, also reset the sec to 60 and other vars you need to reset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation called `interruptible-timer`:

````
// A timer which can be interrupted and picks up where you left off.
//
// Usage:
// ```
// var timer = interruptibleTimer(task, 5000);
// timer.start();    // Start the timer, or resume it after stopping.
// timer.stop();     // Timer continues to run, but task will not be called.
// timer.run();      // Run task now, and start timer again from now.
// timer.reset();    // Stop the timer and reset it to 0.
// ```

var set = window.setTimeout;
var clear = window.clearTimeout;

function interruptibleTimer(fn, interval) {
  var recent = 0;
  var timer;

  // PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
  function now()      { return +new Date(); }
  function delay()    { return recent ? Math.max(0, recent + interval - now()) : interval; }
  function schedule() { timer = set(run, delay()); }

  // PUBLIC APIs
  function start()    { if (!timer) schedule(); }
  function stop()     { clear(timer); timer = 0; }
  function run()      { fn(); recent = now(); schedule(); }
  function reset()    { stop(); recent = 0; }

  return {start, stop, run, reset};
}
````

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot to understand the problem.